# Xamarin.Forms custom loading gif as activity indicator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, activity-indicator

I would just like to know of something is possible as I am very new to Xamarin and I am on a time limit for an assignment. I don't mind some trial and error, but don't want to waste the time if it isn't possible

I want to have an animated gif as an activity indicator (it is a logo).

I have it working in a WebView - is it possible, in Xamarin,Forms to have this appear as an overlay while waiting on long running methods?

For example. if  user clicks on a button, the app gets some info from a webservice then displays in a page. While waiting I would like to show the webview (or any other way to show an animagted gif).

So I am not asking for the code, but just if it is posible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to work this out

With the animated(loading) gif running in the WebView page I called a couple of async methods using following

```
await Task.WhenAll(method1(), method2());
await Navigate.PushAsync(new NextPage(var1, var2));
```

The laoding gif (which is an animated logo) runs until the tasks are complete then navigates to the next page

Comment: The webview you are using is transparent? I tried same way but and it is working the only issue is loader is not transparent. Have you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

Using an **ImageView** apparently this doesn't look like its possible to playback animated Gif's as can be seen here http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17448/animated-gif-in-image-view.

So i very much doubt the **ActivityIndicator** would, if it could.  In the **ActivityIndicator** I can't see any functionality to change the content of the what is shown when it is busy.

You could always create your own animated image view by creating a **custom renderer** instead however.  It isn't particularly hard to cycle images at pre-determined gaps if you have a list of the images split up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Pete, but I don't think I explained it well enough - I have managed to work it out - see below

Answer (score 1):

GIF images can be used in Xamarin forms to show custom activity indicator, since in Xamarin forms it is not possible to show GIF images directly web-view must be used. For android image must be placed inside assets folder and Build Action must be set to AndroidAsset. For iOS image must be placed inside resources and Build Action must be set to BundleResource. AbsoluteLayout can used for placing the image to center, IsBusy property of mvvm helpers nuget can used for controlling the visibility of the activity indicator. Dependency service must used for getting the image path. You can check this https://github.com/LeslieCorrea/Xamarin-Forms-Custom-Activity-Indicator for example.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms now **supports .GIF**, from version 4.4-pre3 and up on iOS, Android and UWP. Before using, first add the .GIF to the platforms projects, or as an embedded resource in the shared project and then use it like a regular image. The API on the Image control has been extended with the **IsAnimationPlaying** bindable property.

For e.g., loader.gif is added in all platform projects, then below code make it animating.

```
<Image Source="loader" IsAnimationPlaying="True" WidthRequest="36" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```